# Pandas indexation missing values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data

Suppose I have the following 2 dataframes:

One where I have a time series which contains missing price values (column 'val') for different id's:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 
                    'year': [2013, 2014, 2015, 2012, 2013],
                    'val': [np.nan, np.nan, 300, np.nan, 150]})

df1
```

Which looks like:

```
  id  year    val
0  1  2013    NaN
1  1  2014    NaN
2  1  2015  300.0
3  2  2012    NaN
4  2  2013  150.0
```

One where I have an price index series over time, where I can calulate the factor of price inflation between different years:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
                    'index': [100, 103, 105, 109, 115]})
df2['factor'] =  df2['index'] / df2['index'].shift()
df2
```

Which looks like:

```
   year  index    factor
0  2011    100       NaN
1  2012    103  1.030000
2  2013    105  1.019417
3  2014    109  1.038095
4  2015    115  1.055046
```

Now suppose I want to do backward indexation for the most recently available price value for a given id (item) using the factor of the second dataframe. Which is the most efficient way of doing this?

So far I tried the following (but this loop is very slow for the large dataset i use, because it only fills 1 time period back for each loop):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['year', 'factor']], how = 'left', on = 'year')
missings = df1['val'].sum()
while df1['val'].isnull().sum() < missings:
    missings = df1['val'].isnull().sum()
    df1.loc[df1['val'].notnull(), 'factor'] = 1
    df1['val'] = df1.groupby('id')['val'].fillna(method='bfill', limit=1)
    df1['val'] = df1['val'] / df1['factor']
df1.drop(columns = 'factor').head()
```

Which yields the following results:

```
  id  year         val
0  1  2013  283.486239
1  1  2014  288.990826
2  1  2015  300.000000
3  2  2012  145.631068
4  2  2013  150.000000
```

So the value for 2014: 300 / 1.038095.
And the value for 2013: 300 / 1.038095 / 1.019417.

Is there any better and faster way to achieve the same results?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is val?

Comment: You can try to remove duplicates from the second dataset before merging. And set the option to get the last/first result depending on how its indexed

Comment: `df2.drop_duplicates('year', keep='first', inplace=False)` Not sure if i understood the question though

Comment: @RushabhMehta val is the value column for example with prices, where for older years the value is missing and needs to get backward filled (corrected for inflation) based on the most recently available price.

Comment: @AndreMotta In the second dataframe each year is only mentioned once, so it has no duplicates. The first dataframe can have the same year multiple times for different id's. How can I make my question clearer for you?

Comment: So you want to fill the first one with the values from the second one where years match?

Comment: @AndreMotta I want to fill the first dataframe with the last available price from the first dataframe corrected for an index from the second dataframe.

Comment: @user7822917 can you have for a same id something like 2015 with a value, 2014 `nan`, 2013 with a value, 2012 and 2011 `nan`? I mean 2 years with a value but at least a year with `nan` between for same id?

Comment: @Ben.T No, I dont have nan values in between, so the given solution works for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.transform.html) on the column `factor` and [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) after inversing the order with `[::-1]`, all in a `groupby` such as:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['year', 'factor']], how = 'left', on = 'year')
df1.loc[df1['val'].notnull(),'factor']=1 #set factor to one where val exists
# here is how to get the factor you want when it's not just before a value
df1['factor'] = df1.groupby('id')['factor'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])
df1['val'] = df1['val'].bfill()/df1['factor'] #back fill val no limitation and divide by factor
print (df1)
  id  year         val    factor
0  1  2013  283.486239  1.058252 #here it's 1*1.038095*1.019417
1  1  2014  288.990826  1.038095 #here it's 1*1.038095
2  1  2015  300.000000  1.000000 
3  2  2012  145.631068  1.030000 #here it's 1*1.03
4  2  2013  150.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! I will look into the functions mentioned.